# How to highlight a value in columns in R

Tags: r

```html
dat<-read.table(text="X Value
Time1 12
Time2 10
Time3 11
Time4 6
",header=TRUE)
```

I want to highlight Values < 12 using colour fonts(e.g., red). So in this example, Time2, Time3 and Time4 and their values will get red colour.

Comment: Do your really mean `<=12` I think it should be `<12`, otherwise all will become red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with packages **knitr** and **kableExtra**:

```
library("dplyr")
library("knitr")
library("kableExtra")
kable(dat) %>%
  row_spec(which(dat$Value < 12), color="red")
```

[image: knitr cable]